# How can I insert safely (sql injection) identifiers in a query using snowflake python connector?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In order to avoid SQL injection attacks I want to use bind variables / query parameters, but those doesn't seem to work for identifiers (like a table name, or a user name)

```
import snowflake.connector
import os
def myfunc(username):
    with snowflake.connector.connect(user=os.environ['SF_USER'], password=os.environ['SF_PASSWORD'], account=os.environ['SF_ACCOUNT']) as ctx:
        cs = ctx.cursor().execute('''SHOW GRANTS TO USER %s''', (username))
        print(cs.rowcount)
        rint(cs.fetchone())
myfunc('TEST2') # Raises a ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error: syntax error line1 at position 20 unexpected ''TEST2''
```

I guess in the above test `TEST2` is inserted as a literal ``` 'TEST2`` and not as an identifier ```"TEST2"`.

If I can't use bind variables / query parameters for this, I guess I would need to construct the string myself  `f'''SHOW GRANTS TO USER {username}'''` but **what options do I have to sanitize the input before the string interpolation**?

By the way, I know that instead of `SHOW GRANTS TO USER "<username>"` I could use `select * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."GRANTS_TO_USERS" where deleted_on is null and grantee_name = '<username2'` which avoid the problem since the in the latter query the username is used as a literal and not an identifier. But I found the `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS` to be lagging (does NOT show the latest changes immediately, delayed by more that 20 minutes in my case).

So what can I use to sanitize the values I'll use as identifiers to prevent SQL injection attacks?

Comment: Have you seen the Bind variables section of the identifier-literal docs https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html

Comment: For anyone who find this answer looking for how to avoid injection attacks in Snowflake in general, the most basic solution is documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#binding-data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@SimeonPilgrim pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052226/how-can-i-insert-safely-sql-injection-iidentfiers-in-a-query-using-snowflake-p/62052515#comment109749082_62052226)  there is a function [`IDENTIFIER`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html) that can be used to convert a bind variable to an identifier.

So instead of `... TO USER %s` use `... TO USER IDENTIFIER(%s)`

```
import snowflake.connector
import os
def myfunc(username):
    with snowflake.connector.connect(user=os.environ['SF_USER'], password=os.environ['SF_PASSWORD'], account=os.environ['SF_ACCOUNT']) as ctx:
        cs = ctx.cursor().execute('''SHOW GRANTS TO USER IDENTIFIER(%s)''', (username))
        print(cs.rowcount)
        rint(cs.fetchone())
myfunc('TEST2') # Works!
```

Comment: Normally, for a self-answer, I'd only up-vote the question, but you get another one for the answer because I've never thought of linking to a comment before. Nice.